# deeply nested json with angular2

Tags: json, angular

i am new in angular2 and trying to display my data which is in json using angular2

below is my json data:

```
{
   "logoEditorData":{
      "logo":{
         "companyNameOption":{
            "fontSize":{
               "currentValue":0,
               "minValue":1,
               "maxValue":100
            },
            "letterSpacing":{
               "currentValue":0,
               "minValue":1,
               "maxValue":100
            },
            "FontCases":[
               "upper",
               "lower"
            ]
         },
         "taglineNameOption":{
            "fontSize":{
               "currentValue":0,
               "minValue":1,
               "maxValue":100
            },
            "letterSpacing":{
               "currentValue":0,
               "minValue":1,
               "maxValue":100
            },
            "FontCases":[
               "upper",
               "lower"
            ]
         },
         "commonSetting":{
            "iconTextSize":{
               "currentValue":0,
               "minValue":1,
               "maxValue":100
            },
            "logoSize":{
               "currentValue":50,
               "minValue":1,
               "maxValue":100
            },
            "iconDistance":{
               "currentValue":40,
               "minValue":1,
               "maxValue":100
            },
            "taglineSize":{
               "currentValue":60,
               "minValue":1,
               "maxValue":100
            }
         },
         "commonFonts":{
            "companyNameFont":{
               "selected":[
                  "sansSerief"
               ],
               "sansSerif":{
                  "fontImage":"..\/src\/images\/sans-serif.png",
                  "fontList":[
                     "open-sans",
                     "lato",
                     "oswald",
                     "roboto",
                     "exo",
                     "ubuntu",
                     "istok"
                  ],
                  "description":"Clean logotypes that convey simplicity, power, and confidence."
               },
               "serif":{
                  "image":"..\/src\/images\/serif.png",
                  "fontList":[
                     "open-sans",
                     "lato",
                     "oswald",
                     "roboto",
                     "exo",
                     "ubuntu",
                     "istok"
                  ],
                  "description":"Clean logotypes that convey simplicity, power, and confidence."
               }
            },
            "taglineNameFont":{
               "selected":[
                  "sansSerief"
               ],
               "sansSerif":{
                  "fontImage":"..\/src\/images\/sans-serif.png",
                  "fontList":[
                     "open-sans",
                     "lato",
                     "oswald",
                     "roboto",
                     "exo",
                     "ubuntu",
                     "istok"
                  ],
                  "description":"Clean logotypes that convey simplicity, power, and confidence."
               },
               "serif":{
                  "image":"..\/src\/images\/serif.png",
                  "fontList":[
                     "open-sans",
                     "lato",
                     "oswald",
                     "roboto",
                     "exo",
                     "ubuntu",
                     "istok"
                  ],
                  "description":"Clean logotypes that convey simplicity, power, and confidence."
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "colors":{
         "image":"abc"
      },
      "layout":{
         "placement":[
            "iconSingle",
            "iconTextLeft",
            "iconTextTop",
            "text"
         ],
         "container":{
            "none":"none",
            "iconOnly":"icon",
            "iconWithText":"both",
            "whole":"whole"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

i created a service for this then try to subscribe my data in my app component with ngfor, i also try to solve my problem using pipes but didn't get expected result.
is there any way we can get data like we do in jquery using $.each with key and value corresponding its nested loop in jquery.

can anyone help me out?

Comment: what do you want to display in HTML?

Comment: same as hierarchy of Json

Comment: is this what you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-sample

Comment: i have already done like this i want it's index key & value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the keys of your JSON object using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Below code will return all the keys inside logoEditorData i.e., logo, colors and layouts. Now you can iterate this keys over json object to find the value. [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-sample)

In TS file

```
constructor(){
  this.jsonDataKeys=Object.keys(this.jsonData.logoEditorData);
}
```

In HTML file

```
<div *ngFor="let item of jsonDataKeys">
   <div>Key : {{item}} Value: {{jsonData.logoEditorData[item] | json}}</div>
  </div>
```